# DataFrame with MultiIndex columns: set values of partial row via dictionary

Tags: pandas, multi-index

```py
from pandas import Index, MultiIndex, DataFrame, NA

columns = MultiIndex.from_product( (["foo", "bar"], list("abc"))   )
index = Index(range(10))
df = DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns, dtype="Float32")
```

```
    foo               bar            
      a     b     c     a     b     c
0  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
5  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
6  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
7  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
8  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
9  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

How can I update the values in position `[0, "foo"]` with a dictionary `foo_sample = {"b": 1.2, "c": 1.3, "a": 1.1}`? I tried, using `pandas 1.4.2`:

```py
df.loc[0, "foo"] = foo_sample        # does nothing.
df.loc[0, "foo"].update(foo_sample)  # does nothing
df.loc[0, "foo"].replace(foo_sample) # does nothing
df.loc[0, "foo"].map(foo_sample)     # replaces <NA> with NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```py
df.loc[0, ("foo", list(foo_sample.keys()))] = foo_sample.values()

print(df)
# Output
      a     b     c     a     b     c
0   1.1   1.2   1.3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
5  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
6  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
7  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
8  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
9  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

See [Advanced indexing with hierarchical index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) in Pandas documentation for additional guidance.

Comment: I am looking for a vectorized solution.

Comment: Right, see my updated answer. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Still a bit dumbfounded why none of the things I tried did anything.